# Using cmd compact with folder name patterns

Tags: windows, cmd

My folder structure is as below:

[image]

How could I use `compact /s /c` only on those folders whose name ends in "Holder" to compress all files recursively within those folders? Thanks

Comment: Your question, or more to the point, the problem you need to research, is 'how do I list directories whose names end with a known string'. Your actual task is irrelevant, you just need to know that, then adjust what you've learned to incorporate the `compact` command.

Comment: Use `COMPACT /?` and read about the `filename` parameter. What does `pattern` mean?

Comment: Using @Compo suggest, the following works: ```for /d %G in ("*Holder") do cd %G && cmd /s /c && cd ..```. Thanks!

Comment: No problem shanlodh, I would suggest that you consider not changing directories unless it is essential to the `compact` command's usage, _(I don't believe it is in this case)_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 10 64-bit

Set folder and / or file compress attribute with compact and cmd for loop.

Set the compress attribute for every folder whose name ends with `holder`. Compress the files that are not system or hidden files in every folder whose folder name ends with `holder`. Stop if COMPACT encounters an error.

CMD:

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %g in ('DIR /ad /b /s "*holder"') do COMPACT /c "%g" 
FOR /f "tokens=*" %g in ('DIR /ad /b /s "*holder"') do FOR /f "tokens=*" %h in ('DIR /a-d /b "%g"') do COMPACT /c "%g\%h"
rem un-set un-compress
FOR /f "tokens=*" %g in ('DIR /ad /b /s "*holder"') do COMPACT /u "%g" 
FOR /f "tokens=*" %g in ('DIR /ad /b /s "*holder"') do FOR /f "tokens=*" %h in ('DIR /a-d /b "%g"') do COMPACT /u "%g\%h"
```

SCRIPT:

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%g in ('DIR /ad /b /s "*holder"') do ECHO COMPACT /c "%%g" 
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%g in ('DIR /ad /b /s "*holder"') do FOR /f "tokens=*" %%h in ('DIR /a-d /b "%%g"') do ECHO COMPACT /c "%%g\%%h"
rem un-set un-compress
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%g in ('DIR /ad /b /s "*holder"') do ECHO COMPACT /u "%%g" 
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%g in ('DIR /ad /b /s "*holder"') do FOR /f "tokens=*" %%h in ('DIR /a-d /b "%%g"') do ECHO COMPACT /u "%%g\%%h"
```

TEST SCRIPT:

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%g in ('DIR /ad /b /s "*holder"') do COMPACT /c "%%g" 
echo. 
echo Set compress attribute of folders whose name ends in holder. 
echo.
pause 
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%g in ('DIR /ad /b /s "*holder"') do FOR /f "tokens=*" %%h in ('DIR /a-d /b "%%g"') do COMPACT /c "%%g\%%h"
echo. 
echo Compress and set compress attribute of files in folders whose folder name ends in holder. 
echo.
pause 
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%g in ('DIR /ad /b /s "*holder"') do COMPACT /u "%%g" 
echo. 
echo Unset compress attribute of folders whose name ends in holder.
echo.
pause 
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%g in ('DIR /ad /b /s "*holder"') do FOR /f "tokens=*" %%h in ('DIR /a-d /b "%%g"') do COMPACT /u "%%g\%%h"
echo. 
echo Un-compress and un-set compress attribute of files in folders whose folder name ends with holder.
exit /b
```